# Can't access Google Cloud SQL instance from different GCP project, despite setting IAM permissions

Tags: python, mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm attempting to access a Google Cloud SQL instance stored on one Cloud Platform project from an App Engine application on another project, and it's not working.

Connections to the SQL instance fail with this error:
`OperationalError: (2013, "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 38")`

I followed the instructions in Google's documentation and added the App Engine service account for the second project to the IAM permissions list for the project housing the Cloud SQL instance (with "Cloud SQL Editor" as the role). The connection details and configuration I'm using in my app are identical to those being used in a perfectly functioning App Engine app housed in the same project as the Cloud SQL instance.

The only thing that seems off about my configuration is that in my second GCP project, while an App Engine service account that looks like the default one (`[MY-PROJECT-NAME]@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`) appears in the IAM permissions list, this service account is *not* listed under the Service Accounts tab of IAM & Admin. The only service account listed is the `Compute Engine default service account`. I haven't deleted any service accounts; there's never been an App Engine default service account listed here, but apart from the MySQL connection the App Engine app runs fine.

Not sure if it's relevant, but I'm running a Python 2.7 app on the App Engine Standard Environment, connecting using MySQLdb.

Answer (score 8):

Figured it out eventually - perhaps this will be useful to someone else encountering the same problem.

**Problem:**

> The problem was that the "Cloud SQL Editor" role is *not* a superset
>   of the "Cloud SQL Client", as I had imagined; "Cloud SQL Editor"
>   allows administration of the Cloud SQL instance, but doesn't allow
>   basic connectivity to the database.

**Solution:**

> Deleting the IAM entry granting Cloud SQL Editor permissions and
>   replacing it with one granting Cloud SQL Client permissions fixed the
>   issue and allowed the database connection to go through.

Comment: I spent half a day trying to figure out why I was getting "Access denied" errors when trying to write to my google sql database and this solved it for me. It was not very intuitive, but you have to add the following roles to your Google API service accountCloud SQL Admin
Cloud SQL Client
Cloud SQL Editor